# Trees have a huge gap before and after

Tags: trees

I am trying to print out a tree by using following packages:

```
\usepackage{epic}     % required by ecltree and fancybox packages
\usepackage{ecltree}  % to draw the GP trees
\usepackage{fancybox} % required by \Ovalbox
\setlength{\GapWidth}{1em}

\thicklines \drawwith{\dottedline{2}}
\newcommand{\gpbox}[1]{\Ovalbox{#1\rule[-.7ex]{0ex}{2.7ex}}}
```

This is my actual code:

```
deep structure, which does not increase the complexity of the problem as we will recursively apply reductions all the same. 
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[!ht]{1cm}
\begin{bundle}{\gpbox{L}}\chunk{\begin{bundle}{\gpbox{L}}\chunk{\begin{bundle}{\gpbox{L}}\chunk{\begin{bundle}{\gpbox{P}}\chunk{\gpbox{2}}\chunk{\gpbox{1}}\end{bundle}}\end{bundle}}\end{bundle}}\end{bundle}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
Moreover, many techniques are available for simplifying $\lambda$-trees. As explained in Section \ref{secReduction}, $\alpha$-conversion could be used to rename nodes in $\lambda$-trees and $\eta$-conversion could be used to take out redundant parts.
```

The tree shows up, however, if I put text before or after the tree, there is a huge gap as you can see in this image:

[image: output].

I also tried to remove the `\begin{center}` `\end{center}` but it doesn't really help. This is how it looks like after the change:

[image: wanted]

Any way to make it just like a normal picture with a normal gap?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what gap you're referring to.

Comment: Can you provide full code starting from `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}`?

Comment: @egreg sorry I updated the same image twice.

Comment: @HarishKumar I am using a template provided by my school, the document class is shown as \documentclass[10pt,code,picins,kaukecopyright,openright,woolshort,dropcaps,verbatim,euler,index,colophon,blacklinks,twoside]{woosterthesis}

Comment: @user1745048 the snippet you just posted it's not enough to reproduce the problem. Is there some other object near the tree? A float, perhaps? Anyway, if you use `center`, you can suppress the `minipage`.

Comment: The best thing you can do is putting the tree in a `figure` environment and let it float, so that LaTeX will find a good place for it, without harming the typesetting of the text.

Comment: Sorry it was my stupidity. If I add more text, the figure will "float" up and the gap will be squeezed small.